# ncurses: mouse works in terminal emulator but not tty(vt)

Tags: mouseevent, ncurses, mc

```
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  assert(OK==keypad(stdscr,TRUE));   
  mousemask(BUTTON1_PRESSED|BUTTON1_RELEASED,NULL));
  assert(has_mouse());
  assert(166==mouseinterval(1));
  refresh();
  for(;;){
    int ch=wgetch(stdscr);
    // Detect mouse event and print coordinates
  }  
  endwin();
```

In terminal emulator (alacritty), mouse coordinates are reported normally after a click of the left button. However, if I `systemctl start gpm` then run it in tty(vt), there is no response at all wherever mouse is clicked.

How can I make it work in tty(vt) as well?

Comment: ncurses has to be configured (compile-time) to work with gpm.  If you compiled it yourself, that may not be configured.  If you are commenting on a prebuilt package, your question should include relevant information (system and package version).

Comment: It's a prebuilt distro package, and [here](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/ncurses#n22) is how they built it.

Comment: The package script doesn't mention gpm, and the [configure script](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/300538725582f4f9adaa5852f2342666be0dc3f6/INSTALL#L949) doesn't turn that on by default.  If the gpm development files happened to be available, it might have been in the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***ncurses*** has to be configured (compile-time) to work with ***gpm***. If you compiled it yourself, that may not be configured. If you are commenting on a prebuilt package, your question should include relevant information (system and package version).

A comment points to [Arch Linux's package](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/ncurses#n22), which does not explicitly turn on *gpm*.  The *gpm* feature is not enabled by default (hint: the [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/300538725582f4f9adaa5852f2342666be0dc3f6/INSTALL#L949) file shows the feature as [**`--with-gpm`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/300538725582f4f9adaa5852f2342666be0dc3f6/aclocal.m4#L8370)), and lacking other clues, is unlikely to be part of the package, unless the development package for gpm happened to be installed on the build-server.

A further comment mentions *midnight commander*.  Whether or not it actually uses ncurses *midnight commander* has not used ncurses' mouse support for quite a while.  Some of that is discussed in [*comments on ncurses versus slang (S-Lang)*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#vs-mc)

You could make this work (ncurses+gpm) either by compiling the package yourself (using `--with-gpm`, taking care to have the development headers and libraries installed), or possibly a bug report to Arch might get that changed.

Comment: midnight commander seems to be using libgpm directly [key.c](https://repo.or.cz/midnight-commander.git/blob/HEAD:/lib/tty/key.c) [mouse.c](https://repo.or.cz/midnight-commander.git/blob/HEAD:/lib/tty/mouse.c)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it's going astray from the question :-)   By the way, if the question's answered, you might *accept* it.